# How to add link to a block in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

There are blocks in drupal like Main Menu, Navigation, Management Etc,

They all appear as a solid text in huge letters, but I want to turn them into links and to act as an actual menu.

Is there any extension that does it, or I would have to code it my self?

I'm a newbie in drupal but I don't want to re-invent the wheels, if it's already provided somewhere.

Edit:

Well, the titles of the block are the solid text indeed, I want to turn them into link, or at least hide them, these letters are so huge and out of place. And if I set label to '' it displays the default word, like 'Navigation'...

[image]

Comment: That's very strange!  Those sound like some of the default menus that come with Drupal.  You're saying that their content is not displayed as links in your website?  Could you provide a URL or some sample code or a screenshot?  These should definitely be regular Drupal menus, so something must be going wrong with your theme or setup if they are just displaying as text...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter `<none>` as the title to hide the block title. Blocks are not made to be pages so there's no point linking to them. Consider a view if you want more complex functions from blocks.